Probability of a 2-Player, Alternating Dart Game
I found an interesting probability question in my college textbook, but my solution differs from the provided answer. I hope this issue can be resolved here.
The Problem:
The following is the PMFs of player $A$ and $B$ in a dart game. We denote $X$ as the Bernoulli random variable for player $A$ that takes the value $1$ if they hit bull's-eye; the same case for player $B$ with the random variable $Y$.
$$
p_{A}(x)= 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{5}&\text{if}\, x= 1\\
\frac{4}{5}&\text{if}\, x=0
\end{cases}
$$
$$
p_{B}(y)= 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{6}&\text{if}\, y= 1\\
\frac{5}{6}&\text{if}\, y=0
\end{cases}
$$
The players take turns alternatively to play and the winner is the player who first hits the bull's-eye. If the game starts with player $A$ making their first throw, find the probability that $A$ wins.
My Attempt:
The probability that $A$ wins on their first throw is $\frac{1}{5}$. The probability that $A$ wins on their second throw is $\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{5}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{5}$. Generally, the probability that $A$ wins on their $n$-th throw is
$$
P(X_{1} = 0,Y_{1}=0,...,X_{n-1}=0,Y_{n-1}=0,X_{n}=1)=\frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{n-1}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n-1}= \frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n-1}
$$
Therefore, the probability that $A$ wins must be the sum as $n\rightarrow \infty$:
$$
P(A \text{ wins}) = \frac{1}{5}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n-1}=\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{3}}=\frac{3}{5}
$$
However, the answer provided in the textbook is $\frac{2}{3}$. Did I overlook something in my work?

If $p=P(\text{A wins})$ then $p=\frac15+\frac45\frac56\times p$. From this we find $p=\frac35$. So I think you are correct.

Seems fine, what is the source material?

It is a textbook published by my local university titled 'Essential Mathematics for Pre-University'. Of course I formalized the question better here.

$3/5$ is the correct answer. You can also view the problem as follows, to avoid the infinite sum of vanishing exponential terms:
$A$ has a $6/30$ chance of winning in the first round. $B$ has a $4/30$ chance of winning in the first round. There is a $20/30$ chance that nobody wins in the first round, and the process repeats. Since we play until someone wins, we can ignore the probability of nobody winning and just compare the chance of either player winning in any particular round, which works out to $3/5$.

This is a refreshing take. Since each round is independent with the total probability of winning is $1/3$, we can think of the problem as a conditional event: given that someone won this round, what is the probability that it is player $A$? This yields $\frac{\frac{1}{5}}{\frac{1}{3}} = \frac{3}{5}$. Thank you!
